# XPath binding to read InnerXml in wpf

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xpath, binding

Is there a way to read the entire InnerXml (or OuterXml) using XPath binding in wpf?

**Sample Data Provider**

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="SampleDataProvider" IsInitialLoadEnabled="True" IsAsynchronous="False" XPath="SampleDataProvider">
    <x:XData>
        <SampleData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="">
            <Property ID="BlinkData">
                <Blink>
                    <Property ID="Name">Blink1</Property>
                    <Property ID="Speed">400</Property>
                    <Property ID="Value1">0</Property>
                    <Property ID="Value2">100</Property>
                </Blink>
            </Property>
        </SampleData>
    </x:XData>
</XmlDataProvider>
```

**Sample Window**

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SampleDataProvider}" XPath="/SampleData/Property[@ID='BlinkData']" />
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

I am expecting to see the entire InnerXml in the textbox. But unfortunately I see only the node values, like Blink14000100.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK! I guess I found the answer. 
*XPath in wpf would internally return an XmlNode initially and this can be intercepted by adding another attribute to the Binding statement, **Path**.*

For example,

```
<TextBox Width="100" Height="100">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SampleDataProvider}" XPath="/SampleData/Property[@ID='BlinkData']" Path="InnerXml" />
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox >
```

Notice the **Path** attribute set to InnerXml in the Binding statement! Additionally add a converter to this and do whatever you want!

Found this information out here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.xpath.aspx